# Many domains with the same site, each one with it's own db

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

for a project i need to run multiple copies of the same web site, each one on a different domain with a different database.

I plan of doing that this way

- create an hosting for each website with a personal database and a website
- keep the code updated across the websites using git
- update the database using an orm

The problem is that i need an unique login page across the various sites.
I think that the user enter the username on a main site and then it' redirected on the personal site where he insert his password, but this way i have to keep in sync the login data.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Not knowing what technology you're going to use, I assume you are running on a Linux or Unix host. You could have your website view handling changes to users (create, password change etc.) trigger a shell script that could keep the data in sync across the databases if you insist on using separate databases. Otherwise you could let each site connect to two databases - one for content, one for user management. However it smells like race-conditions and a lot of mess. You might want to rethink why you want to do this.

Comment: The project is on a linux hosting, it's developed in php using Laravel. I know that there can be problem with an approach like this, but the app need to scale easy and this is the only way i find to achieve this

Comment: The main reason of doing this is separate the various component of the application. If a website is down for whatever reason the others continue to work

Comment: Why not go with a load balancer or a CDN based solution? Those technologies are made to handle things like this.

Comment: The pages are only for signed in users, so a cdn isn't a good choice.

Comment: I would definitely go with a load balancer then - e.g. https://www.linode.com/nodebalancers

Comment: It's an idea, but if i understand how a load balancer works this way i have many small databases replicated across various server, so if one of the db is huge it take space on many servers

Comment: Keeping things simple is actually a great way of getting high availability of services. I would recommend that you start out with a simple system of just one server, use nginx instead of Apache, and see how things go from there. You can easily scale up to a bigger system if needed, but you will be able to support a surprisingly high number of concurrent users if you do the right way. I think you will find that things run rock solid, at the only time you might experience problems is when you make changes or do updates, but that can be scheduled.